# List all files in a folder without subfolders in R

Tags: r, windows

I use `li <- list.files(path, full.names = F, include.dirs = F)`. To my surprise `li` also contains folders if there are any. I thought I can switch that off using `include.dirs = F`. Am I wrong?
I am using R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) on Windows.

Comment: From help `include.dirs logical. Should subdirectory names be included in recursive listings? (They always are in non-recursive ones).`

Comment: `Should subdirectory names be included in recursive listings?` => No!  
That is why I set it to `FALSE`. Do I get that totally wrong as a non-native speaker?

Comment: but you don't have a recursive listing. By default, `recursive = FALSE`

Comment: Ok. That answers the question. However, I don't understand why they set it like this - but that is a different issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Christoph, If you refer to the help provided by R, the statement written is

`include.dirs: logical. Should subdirectory names be included in recursive listings? (They always are in non-recursive ones).`.

I want to highlight the term: **(They always are in non-recursive ones).**

As rightly said by @RichardTelford, by default, the value of `recursive = FALSE`.

If you really want to do the task, you can give a try to this code:

```
setdiff(list.files(path,full.names=T),list.dirs(path,recursive=F))
```

Comment: Due to windows, I needed:
`lf <- list.files(path,full.names=T)`
`ld <- list.dirs(path,recursive=F)`

`lf[match(setdiff(normalizePath(lf),normalizePath(ld)), normalizePath(lf))]` which is the desired result...

Answer (score 3):

The related answers are quite relevant here as they are related: :-)

However, if you are looking for R scripts in a folder and want to leave out the other things: {subfolders, rds files, etc}.

This is one way to do it:

```
list.files(pattern = ".R$")
```

$ in regex expressions looks at the end of a string

^ similarly looks for expressions at the start of a string